# Make a record from a list of Text values

Tags: list, haskell, record

Starting from a list of Text, I'd like to convert this into a Record where each field corresponds to a value in the list.

```hs
import Data.Text

data MyRecord = MyRecord {
  rOne :: Text,
  rTwo :: Text,
  rThree :: Int
}

txt :: [Text]
txt = ["foo", "bar", "12"]
```

I'm not sure how to (cleanly) proceed from the list of Text up to the record. It is assumed that this list will always be of the same size (here, 3) and there will always be an Int-like value in third position.

The minimal naive working version I've got to is so desperately hacky that I can't resign myself to committing this into the codebase:

```hs
-- assuming RecordWildCards
readText :: [Text] -> MyRecord
readText l =
  let rOne = l !! 0
      rTwo = l !! 1
      rThree :: Int = read $ l !! 2
  in MyRecord {..}
```

What would be a more Haskell-friendly way of doing this?

Note: what I'm actually after is parsing a comma-separated file into a list of `MyRecord`, without a csv library. The rows will not contain commas inside a value, so splitting on commas can be considered safe here (e.g. `values = T.splitOn "," <$> lines`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure the list is three elements long, you could use

```
readText :: [Text] -> MyRecord
readText [rOne, rTwo, rThreeText] = MyRecord {..}
   where rThree :: Int = read rThreeText
```

Still, you might wish to make the pattern matching exhaustive, just in case:

```
readText :: [Text] -> MyRecord
readText [rOne, rTwo, rThreeText] = MyRecord {..}
   where rThree :: Int = read rThreeText
readText _ = error "readText: list length /= 3"
```

Comment: `readText [rOne, rTwo, read -> rThree] = MyRecord {..}` also seems like a nice option.